# Call to a member function format() on a non-object when using DateTime

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I am trying to convert a date format from 31/12/15 to 2015-12-31 but I am having problems with this, I have tried `strtotime` methods with no luck as I keep getting 2031-12-15.

I have now changed the method to this:

```
$csv_array[4] = '31/12/15';    
$insert_csv['custom_10'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $csv_array[4])->format('Y-m-d');
```

which seems to be echoing the correct format but also throwing an error of:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

Comment: [Check your version of PHP as this works on PHP 5.5](https://eval.in/319480). Try [this](https://eval.in/319481) and see if that works.

Comment: You should post it as the answer

Comment: well I'm trying work out why its throwing an error, sorry, should have clarified.